# Unable to trigger didReceive notification delegate when you bring the app from background to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ios11

I have implemented push notification for ios10.  Tapping on the notification alert would trigger "didReceive" delegate, were i save the notification in coredata or silent notification if i m in foreground. The problem is if i receive a stack of notification in background and When i bring my app to foreground from background, Is there a possibility to call "didReceive" delegate or any other push notification delegate were i could sync my items to coredata.

**Note**
I don't want to sync(didReceive or any delegate) the items in background using silent notification nor tapping on the alert. It should sync automatically the stack of push notification when i bring the app to foreground

```
     func handleInboxNotification(didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    if let inboxValue = userInfo["inbox"] as? String, let value = inboxValue.boolValue(), value {
        let mappedMessage = MessageCenterSDK.shared.constructReorderedDictionary(userInfo: userInfo)
        MessageCenterDataManager.shared.synchronize(messages: mappedMessage)
        messageCenterDelegate?.didFindNewMessages(hasNewMessages: true)
    }
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    /// Handle outbound remote
    handleInboxNotification(didReceiveRemoteNotification: response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, but my target was for iOS 13 & I'm using `BGTaskScheduler` to fetch data from the server in the background as well in terminated state.

I too want to trigger the notification when the app is in background. But not tapped but that seems to be not possible so we have changed our implementation by enabling background mode and it worked for me.

Hope it also helps.

For more reference on `BGTaskScheduler`, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler

Comment: @summit Were you able to fetch  the push notification dictionary that has been queued?

Comment: You need to get the required data from server like from API or socket, as without tapping you cannot get notification's response.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use willpresent delegate in appDelegate

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}
```

This delegate is called when a notification comes in foreground

Comment: As i mentioned earlier in the comment. Tapping on the alert works fine.. When i move the app from foreground to background..didReceive or any available delegagte should work

Comment: @user578386 i have updated my answer. you need to use this function for foreground notifications